# What is the implementation principle of MTKLog based on Android platform？？

Tags: android, mtkview

I want to learn a little bit about how MTKLog records logs, MTKLog can store all kinds of logs in a local file, it's amazing, anybody know? Please give advice, thank you

Comment: Is anyone here? Help!

Comment: First of all, this is not a discussion chat, so that it can take some time to get answers. Second, your question is to broad. To gain a higher chance of getting an answer have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.